# ECM Sitecore Upload Receipts From .CSV Error

Tags: file-upload, sitecore, ecm

Has anyone received the following error when trying to upload receipts in Sitecore Email Campaign Manager? It looks like the file is not being saved in the temp folder. The error is not consistent. It happens sporadically.

[image]

Comment: Do you have a temp folder in your web root? Make sure it has NetworkService write permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the temp folder has `Network Service` write permissions on it.

Also ensure these steps have been done:

1) Change the Identity in Application Pool as  `Network Service`

2) Make sure that the website folder and all its descendants and the data folder and all its descendants have read and write access for `Network Service`.